# Excel 2010 VBA Autofill entire column

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I am having trouble getting VBA to do the equivalent of Autofilling an entire row (such as when you double click on the plus sign of a cell with a formula and it autofills the appropriate number of columns).

Along Column A I have a list of dates.  Along Row 3 I have a list of formulas.  How do I write a macro which will effectively do this:

```
For i = 2 to Columns.Count
    'FillDown the whole of Column i with the formula in Cells(3,i)
Next i
```

I want the fill down, not just a copy of the exact formula... Does anyone know how this can be done?  I've got a method which is taking about 20 minutes so far but when I do this process manually it takes not very much time at all, so I think there must be a much faster way.

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `Autofill` with a destination range.

Something like:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A12")
```

[EDIT] Or:

```
Range("A1").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, firstColNumber), Cells(1, lastColNumber))
```

Comment: Would the range need to be changed with each column? i.e. would I have to put Range("A2:A12") every time or update it to Range("B2:B12"), etc...?  I ask because I am dealing with column numbers and not letters.

Comment: A variant of this worked fine!  So others know, the solution I used, based on this answer, was:
    `Cells(3, i).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(NumberOfRows, i))`