# VBA Excel 2010 - AutoFill not Filling

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to autofill to the next column along, I set the ranges, I checked them and they are selected using `.Select` but when I run the code it bugs out saying "AutoFill method of Range class failed"

```
LastRow = [C65000].End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = [IV5].End(xlToLeft).Column

Set AutoFillSource = Range(Cells(5, LastColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
Set AutoFillRangeTo = Range(Cells(5, LastColumn + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn + 1))

AutoFillSource.AutoFill Destination:=AutoFillRangeTo
```

I have looked at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889987/excel-2010-vba-autofill-entire-column) but it doesnt resolve it, I also looked at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) to see if I missed anything but also came up empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target range has to include the source range.  Use:

```
Set AutoFillRangeTo = Range(Cells(5, LastColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn + 1))
```

Comment: Now I see where I went wrong, knew it would be something simple. Thanks